# How to solve error of Multiple definition of swap in C

Tags: c, function, multiple-definition-error, function-definition

I am getting error 'multiple definition of swap' from swap function. This code is for selection sort.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void BiDirectionalSelectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = n - 1;  i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        int min = arr[i], max = arr[i];
        int min_i = i, max_i = i;
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {
            if (arr[k] > max)
            {
                max = arr[k];
                max_i = k;
            }

            else if (arr[k] < min)
            {
                min = arr[k];
                min_i = k;
            }
        }


        swap(arr, i, min_i);

        if (arr[min_i] == max)
            swap(arr, j, min_i);
        else
            swap(arr, j, max_i);
    }
}

int swap (int arr[], int *i, int *j)
{
    int temp = arr[*i];
    arr[*i] = arr[*j];
    arr[*j] = temp;
    return arr;
}

static void Main()
{
    int arr[] = { 20, 15, 8, 10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 1 };
    int n = arr;
    BiDirectionalSelectionSort(arr, n);
    printf("Array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf(arr[i] + " ");
    printf("/n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details.

Comment: What compiler are you using, and how are you calling it?  You should be getting other errors, particularly with `Main`.

Comment: in C++ the functions should be declared before they are used.

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward-declare the prototype of the function, so that while the function is called, compiler is aware of the function return type and expected arguments.

Add

```
int swap (int [], int *, int *);
```

after the `include` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a method signature `int swap(int arr[], int *i, int *j);` before use (i.e. before BiDirectional...). As it is, C creates an "implicit declaration" that doesn't line up with what you've written. If you're using gcc, you can add -Wall or -Wimplicit or -Wimplicit-function-declaration to the command line so it tells you that this is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler reads the file from top to bottom. If it sees `swap` by `swap(arr, i, min_i);` inside of `BiDirectionalSelectionSort`, it doesn't know what it is.

You either need to:

1. Use a forward declaration for the function `swap` and place it before the definition of `BiDirectionalSelectionSort`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap (int** arr, int i, int j);           // <------------ HERE

static void BiDirectionalSelectionSort (int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = n - 1;  i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        int min = arr[i], max = arr[i];
        int min_i = i, max_i = i;
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {
            if (arr[k] > max)
            {
                max = arr[k];
                max_i = k;
            }

            else if (arr[k] < min)
            {
                min = arr[k];
                min_i = k;
            }
        }


        swap(&arr, i, min_i);

        if (arr[min_i] == max)
            swap(&arr, j, min_i);
        else
            swap(&arr, j, max_i);
    }
}

void swap (int **arr, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = (*arr)[i];
    (*arr)[i] = (*arr)[j];
    (*arr)[j] = temp;
    return;
}

int main (void)
{
    int arr[] = { 20, 15, 8, 10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 1 };
    size_t n = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (*arr);
    BiDirectionalSelectionSort(arr, n);
    printf("Array:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);      
    }        
}
```

or

2. Place the definition of `swap` before the function definition of `BiDirectionalSelectionSort`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap (int **arr, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = (*arr)[i];
    (*arr)[i] = (*arr)[j];
    (*arr)[j] = temp;
    return;
}

static void BiDirectionalSelectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = n - 1;  i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        int min = arr[i], max = arr[i];
        int min_i = i, max_i = i;
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {
            if (arr[k] > max)
            {
                max = arr[k];
                max_i = k;
            }

            else if (arr[k] < min)
            {
                min = arr[k];
                min_i = k;
            }
        }


        swap(&arr, i, min_i);

        if (arr[min_i] == max)
            swap(&arr, j, min_i);
        else
            swap(&arr, j, max_i);
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int arr[] = { 20, 15, 8, 10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 1 };
    size_t n = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (*arr);
    BiDirectionalSelectionSort(arr, n);
    printf("Array:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);      
    }        
}
```

---

Side Note:

`static void Main()` - This head for `main()` is deprecated in *four* different kind of ways. From left-to-right:

1. `main()` can't be qualified with `static`. At least not the "main" `main()`. You could have a `main()` function in a different source file and declare it `static` but that is a different case.
2. The return value of `main()` shall be of integer type, commonly `int`, not `void`.
3. The linker is case-sensitive. `Main` is a different identifier than `main`.
4. To be fully standard compliant the parameter list of `main` shall not be empty, use `(void)` instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for giving solution and fixing the tiny error of the code. It seems the code run well, but there is no output display. I'm getting few warning messages that said  'swap' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @tyler First, Which of the two versions/methods do you using?

Comment: the both version comes out the same warning.

Comment: @tyler Ah Ok, so it has something to do with your code. I'm currently checking.

Comment: @tyler Your code had several problematic issues. Too much to explain all in detail. Usually I don't do that, but I fixed all. Take a look at what I have changed. Now everything works as it should and gives the desired the output.